# Converting Excel functions into R

Tags: excel, r, for-loop, dataframe, finance

I have two excel functions that I am trying to convert into R:

```
numberShares
=IF(AND(N213="BOH",N212="BOH")=TRUE,P212,IF(AND(N213="BOH",N212="Sell")=TRUE,ROUNDDOWN(Q212/C213,0),0))

marketValue
=IF(AND(N212="BOH",N213="BOH")=TRUE,C213*P212,IF(AND(N212="Sell",N213="Sell")=TRUE,Q212,IF(AND(N212="BOH",N213="Sell")=TRUE,P212*C213,IF(AND(N212="Sell",N213="BOH")=TRUE,Q212))))
```

The cells that are referenced include:

- c = closing price of a stock
- n = position values of either "buy or hold" or "sell"
- p = number of Shares
- q = market value, assuming $10,000 initial equity (number of shares*closing price)

and the tops of the two output columns that i am trying to recreate look like this:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grmLV.png)

So far, in R I have constructed a dataframe with the necessary four columns:
[data.frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biPSt.png)

I just don't know how to write the functions that will populate the number of shares and market value columns. For loops? ifelse?

Again, thank you!!

Comment: you're on the right track with `ifelse()`. Also look at `?Logic`, `?Comparison` and `?round`. You should more or less be able to walk right through your existing code replacing things with the R equivalent and it will work.

Comment: I'd recommend using more traditional `if {} else {}` statements. `ifelse()` doesn't always funciton in a manner that is intuitive.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen I agree, it's important to understand the difference between `if` and `ifelse`. `if` should be used for control statements and it takes a single logical argument, whereas `ifelse` takes a vector argument.

Answer (score 4):

Covert the AND()'s to infix "&";  the "=" to "==";  and the IF's to ifelse() and you are halfway there. The problem will be in converting your cell references to array or matrix references, and for that task we would have needed a better description of the data layout:

```
numberShares <- 
  ifelse( N213=="BOH" & N212=="BOH",  
         #Perhaps PosVal[213] == "BOH" & PosVal[212] == "BOH"
      # ... and very possibly the 213 should be 213:240 and the 212 should be 212:239
             P212, 
             ifelse( N213=="BOH" & N212=="Sell" ,
                         round(Q212/C213, digits=0),
                         0))
```

(You seem to be returning incommensurate values which seems preeety questionable.) Assuming this is correct code despite my misgivings the next translation involves apply the same substitutions in this structure (although you seem to be missing an else-consequent in the last IF function:

```
marketValue <- 
 IF( AND(N212="BOH", N213="BOH")=TRUE, 
           C213*P212, 
           IF(AND(N212="Sell",N213="Sell")=TRUE, 
                     Q212, 
                     IF( AND(N212="BOH",N213="Sell")=TRUE, 
                            P212*C213, 
                            IF(AND(N212="Sell",N213="BOH")=TRUE, 
                                         Q212))))
```

(Your testing for `AND( .,.)=TRUE` is I believe unnecessary in Excel and certainly unnecessary in R.)

Comment: Thank you! I am new to conditional statements in excel, too hahaHow do I reference cells in R, for example "previous position." I have constructed a dataframe with all the appropriate data and with your help can probably

Comment: Thank you! I am new to conditional statements in excel, too! How do I reference cells in R, for example "previous position." I have constructed a dataframe <http://i.imgur.com/BAyJR.png> with all the appropriate data, but don't know how to differentiate between Df$position[i] and Df$position[i-1]

Comment: There is no notion of "previous position" in R. The Reduce function lets you "roll" along a vector.  For loops can be used.  You can also  subtract a shifted vector from a (shortened) vector with `vec[-length(vec)] - vec[-1]`. If the operation is "-" there is of course the `diff` function that does that all in one call. There is also a very useful function named "embed".